# Mapping a web directory in windows

Tags: windows

I would like to know if it is possible to **map a web directory in windows**.

That is to say, that a user, can have access only to a web directory, for example, www.site.com/directory/ and that from the windows explorer can add, delete, modify, etc... as if it were a computer unit. And that all this is in the safest way possible.

I tried to add it from "Connect network drive" but I didn't get it. I don't know the procedure to follow in this case or even if this is possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you want to do is called an FTP server. You should check it out ;)